# I need some suggetions on a clock

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a working clock but instead of running forward I need it to count down
here is the code I am working with at moment

```
 import flash.utils.Timer;  
 import flash.events.TimerEvent;  

 var looper: Timer = new Timer(100);  
 looper.start();  
 looper.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, loopF);
 function loopF(event:TimerEvent):void{  
 var time: Date = new Date(); 

 //time variables

 var hours:* = time.getHours();  
 var minutes:* = time.getMinutes();  
 var seconds:* = time.getSeconds();  
 var hourStrg:String;   
 var minuteStrg:String;
 var secondStrg:String;

 //time text

if(String(seconds).length < 2){
seconds = "0" + seconds;
}
if(String(minutes).length < 2){
minutes = "0" + minutes;
}
if(hours > 11){
ampm_txt.text = "PM";
} else {
ampm_txt.text = "AM";
}
if(hours > 12){
hours = hours - 12;
}
if (String(hours).length < 2){
hours = "0" + hours;
} 
time_txt.text = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

}
```

maybe some one knows a simple way to change this to counting down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code you could do something like this:
Create a global Date object just before starting the timer and set the timer's delay to 1000ms.

Inside the callback function of your timer we can get the number of times the timer has been fired since it started. With this number (and the knowledge the timer fires every second) we can simply subtract this value multiplied by 1000 from the global Date object to make it count backwards.

```
import flash.utils.Timer;  
import flash.events.TimerEvent;  

var looper:Timer = new Timer(1000);  
var now:Date=new Date();
looper.start();  
looper.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, loopF);
function loopF(event:TimerEvent):void{  
    var time:Date = new Date(now.getTime() - Timer(event.currentTarget).currentCount * 1000); 

    //time variables

    var hours:* = time.getHours();  
    var minutes:* = time.getMinutes();  
    var seconds:* = time.getSeconds();  
    var hourStrg:String;   
    var minuteStrg:String;
    var secondStrg:String;

    //time text

    if(String(seconds).length < 2){
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    if(String(minutes).length < 2){
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if(hours > 11){
        ampm_txt.text = "PM";
    } else {
        ampm_txt.text = "AM";
    }
    if(hours > 12){
        hours = hours - 12;
    }
    if (String(hours).length < 2){
        hours = "0" + hours;
    } 
    time_txt.text = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

}
```

Comment: thank you that was what I was looking for to reverse the clock. one more question is there simple way to set the start hours, minutes, seconds for the same timer

Comment: You can set the time directly in the Date constructor. e.g. `var now:Date=new Date(60000); // will set the start time to one minute (60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds)`
**Caution:** This is dependent on the timezone settings of your computer. If it's set to GMT+8 for example, your countdown would start at one minute + 8 hours. To compensate modify the time calculation inside the loop like this: `var time:Date = new Date((now.getTime() + now.timezoneOffset * 60000) - Timer(event.currentTarget).currentCount * 1000);`

Comment: that worked great for me thank you. I like ask you one last thing say my clock text is green but once the count reaches say one minute could I turn it another color?